# How can I set my Flycheck Perl include path?

Tags: flycheck, use-package, perl

I am using Flycheck using `use-package` like so:

```
(use-package flycheck
  :ensure t
  :init
  (global-flycheck-mode))
```

I followed https://randstructure.wordpress.com/2015/06/21/using-emacs-flycheck-with-perl-and-perlbrew/ and tried adding the

```
'(flycheck-perl-include-path
(quote
("/myhomedir/myprojectdir")))
```

and it does not work.

Answer (score 4):

```
(use-package flycheck
  :ensure t
  :init (global-flycheck-mode)
  (setq flycheck-perl-include-path '("/home/your/path/lib" 
"/home/your/other/path/lib")))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also set include paths per project or directory.
Add a directory local variable **flycheck-perl-include-path** with a list of directory strings. Or just create a **.dir-locals.el** file with

```
((cperl-mode
  (flycheck-perl-include-path . ("../lib/" "path/to/you/lib"))))
```

Comment: One, I think there is an extra set of outer parens that are not needed. Two, I am getting error: "Symbol’s function definition is void: flycheck-perl-include-path". Suggestions?

Comment: I think extra parens are needed. For e.g., if your directory has multiple languages, you need to set `((cperl-mode ...) (python-mode ...))` etc... I am not sure about the symbol's def void error.

Comment: Ah, ok on the extra parens then. I'll have to investigate the other issue.